# How to add a user to a telegram channel using telegram cli and the users ID (not username)?

Tags: telegram

This works:

```
bin/telegram-cli -W -e "channel_invite My_Channel @USERNAME"
```

But this does not:

```
bin/telegram-cli -W -e "channel_invite My_Channel 12345678"
```

In the second example I am using the user's ID. And I want to stick to using the ID, because some users don't have their usernames set. Any idea how to do this using the ID and not the username?

Answer (score 0):

Took me forever to find [this](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/issues/844). Solution is to do this:

```
bin/telegram-cli -W -e "channel_invite My_Channel user#12345678"
```

Notice the **user#** part.